# In $\mathbb {R}^{2}$ show that $\big\lbrace\left(x,\,0\right)\mid\;-1<x<1\big\rbrace$ is neither open or closed

Tags: general-topology

I can show that it is not closed be cause the complement $(-\infty ,1]\cup [1,\infty )$ is not open, but I can't prove that it is not open. 
Anyone have any hint ?

Comment: Note this is not in R but R^2.  That makes all the difference.  Unfortunately the complement is not $(-\infty 1]\cup [1,\infty)$  It's $\{(x,y)| y \ne 0\}\cup \{(x,0)|x \le -1\}\cup\{x,0|x \ge 1\}$.

Comment: In R, (-1,1) *IS* open but in R^2,  $ (-1,1)\times \{0\}$, which is what this set is, is not open.

Comment: Use the closed = contains all it's limit points definition. And show (-1,0) and (1,0) are limit points.  For open use the open = all points are interior and show that any neighborhood of any $(x,0)$ will contain $(w,y)$ where $y$ is not zero and so not be in the set so $(x,0)$ can not be an interior point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to recall the following important definitions.

**Definition 1.** For $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$ and $\epsilon >0$, we write
$$B_\epsilon(x,y)=\bigg\{(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2:\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}<\epsilon\bigg\}.$$ The set $B_\epsilon(x,y)$ is called *open disc* with center $(x,y)$ and radius $\epsilon$.

**Definition 2.** Let $A\subset\Bbb R^2$. Then $A$ is *open* if for each $(x,y)\in A$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x,y)\subset A$.

Equivalently, we get

**Definition 3.** Let $A\subset\Bbb R^2$. Then $A$ is *not open* if there exists $(x,y)\in A$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$, we have $B_\epsilon(x,y)\not\subset A$.

Let's go back to your question: Let $$A=\{(x,0):-1<x<1\}.$$ Your proof that this set $A$ is not closed because (as what you have said) $(-\infty,-1]\cup [1,+\infty)$ is not open is **wrong**. In here, we are expecting that $A^c\subset\Bbb R^2$.

$(i)$ This is how to show that $A$ is not closed. Observe that 
$$A^c=\{(x,y):y≠0\}\cup\{(x,0):x≤−1\}\cup\{(x,0):x≥1\}.$$
Consider $(1,0)\in A^c$. Then, for any $\epsilon>0$, we have $$B_\epsilon(1,0)\not\subset A^c\qquad\text{do you know why? Try to draw.}$$
This tells us (see Definition 3 applied to the set $A^c$) that the set $A^c$ is not open. Therefore, $A$ is not closed.

$(ii)$ Choose $(x,y)\in A$. Then, for any $\epsilon>0$, we have $$B_\epsilon(x,y)\not\subset A\qquad\text{again, do you know why? Try to draw.}$$
Again, by using Definition 3, we conclude that $A$ is not open.

If you have questions, just ask me. God bless...

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set:

$$S_e=\{(x,y)|-1\le x \lt 1,-e\le y\le e\}$$

for some $e\ge 0$.

For any $e\gt0$ the set is open, because we can find an open 
disc neighbourhood for every point in it.

If $e=0$ then there is no open disc neighbourhood in $\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically we can see like this , observe that there exists a neighborhood such that it contains points other than the set you gave.

Can you figure it out now?

[image]

It may help!